# JavaScript - Credit Card 16 digit Validation and must be a number not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw this code and tried adding that into my code.

> ```
>  function validate_creditcardnumber()
>  {
>  var re16digit=/^\d{16}$/
>  if (CreditCardNumber.value.search(re16digit)==-1)
>  alert("Please enter your 16 digit credit card numbers");
>  return false;
>  }
> ```

My code below:

```
function confirmSubmit() 
{    
var re16digit = /^\d{16}$/

if (document.getElementById("txtCreditCardNumber").value == "" ||
    isNaN(document.getElementById("txtCreditCardNumber").value) ||
    (document.getElementById("txtCreditCardNumber").value.search(re16digit) == -1)) {
    alert("Credit Card number must be a numeric value.");
    document.getElementById("txtCreditCardNumber").focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

There wasn't any error shown but when I ran the code, only the .value == " " was working. The other 2 didn't work. I need to have these requirements: Cannot be empty, must be a number and must be 16 digits. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try?  That'll help us not retread the same ground.  Also, "Error in Credit Card Form" is not something someone would search for if they had your issue. What would you search for on Google to try to solve this problem? Whatever that is should be your title. If you get an error when you try to run this code; what error do you get?

Comment: You should first replace everything that's not a number with empty string, then check if you have 16 digits
var is_ccnumber = yourstring.replace(/[^0-9]/,'').match(/^[0-9]{16}$/)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm sorry. New to this site. I have already edited it. Hope it is enough.

Comment: @Sly I don't quite understand. Just started Java 2 days ago. How do  u change those that are not a number to a string?

Comment: It's not java it's javascript (very different ;) ). Removing non-digits : CreditCardNumber.value = CreditCardNumber.value.replace(/[^0-9]/gi , '');

Comment: @Sly Typo. Sorry! Having to learn both at the same time.. So I add it in the if{ } ?

Comment: Then your regexp is ok :
 function validate_creditcardnumber()
 {
 var re16digit=/^\d{16}$/;
 if ( ! CreditCardNumber.value.match(re16digit) ) {
 alert("Please enter your 16 digit credit card numbers");
 return false; } else { return true; }
 }

Comment: @Sly But I'm using external .js I have to nest everything in the Submit button. If I create another function won't it not work? I have got other codes all nested in the function confirmSubmit() .

Comment: you have to run your test on the submit event of the form
<form onsubmit="return validate_creditcardnumber()"> and the funciton should return true if cc number is ok, false otherwise

Comment: @Sly I didn't use form. I'm using <label for="cardNumber">Card Number:</label<inputtype="text"name="cardNumber"id="txtCreditCardNumber" size="35" /> 
Is there no way to just run it in the js itsely by using || ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont put together, separate it. after

```
//your alert("Credit Card number must be a numeric value.");
    document.getElementById("txtCreditCardNumber").focus();
    return false;
   }
```

//// create the VAR & add in the{ code }